# the low sensitivity of a dome mounted tweeter in sound testing

Tags: product-testing, sound

What is the common reason and how to solve the low sensitivity of a dome mounted tweeter in sound testing? The testing software is a Soundcheck dome tweeter, and the sensitivity of sound testing is low. What is the usual reason and how to solve it? The testing software is soundcheck

Comment: Test it in an anechoic chamber against others then you have a real comparison, anything else is flawed.

Comment: you solve low sensitivity of a peak by choosing a more efficient speaker

Answer (score 0):

Usual reason: efficiency sacrificed for flat response and/or low cost.